# How to write Python b"mystring" in C#

Tags: c#, python, api

Short Story:
I tried

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mystring")
```

but it seems not to be working...

Long Story:
I am trying to call an API and I have this python sample code available:

```
userpass = username + ":" + password
encoded_credentials = b"Basic " + base64.b64encode(userpass.encode('ascii'))
headers = {'Version': '2.0', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': encoded_credentials}
url = 'https://' + server_ip + '/api/help/capabilities'
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

The c# code I made is:

```
string userpass = username + ":" + password;
byte[] encodedbytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userpass);
var encoded_credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Basic ") + Convert.ToBase64String(encodedbytes);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + server_ip + "/api/help/capabilities");
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", encoded_credentials);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()
```

And the result I get is 401, unauthorized... so I believe I miss something in the encoding procedure of the username-password!

Comment: Your call to `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Basic ") + Convert.ToBase64String(encodedbytes);` will return something like `System.Byte[]asdafafa` because ToString is getting called on the `byte[]`  returned by Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Basic "). You want to at least do `Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Basic ")) + Convert.ToBase64String(encodedbytes);` so you are concatenating 2 strings.

Comment: You're not adding the `Version` and `Accept` headers in the C# version. That might not be the root cause but can't be helping.

Comment: Thank you both, these were correct points! Actually Ben is answering my question as it is asked in the title... Yet, none of the two seems to solve my authorization problem! Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var encoded_credentials = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userpass));
```

That is the answer to my "Long Story" question!
I managed to figure out after debugging the python code (that did authorize), so I took the encoded_credentials and used it in my c# code, so it successfully authorized too...
Then I compared the faulty value to the correct and with a couple of tries, I ended up with the correct one!

This leads me to the conclusion that the correct answer to the "Short Story" question is just:

```
"mystring"
```